# Doctrine object incomplete when no session cookie, why?

Tags: php, session, doctrine-orm, symfony

I've encountered a silly problem this morning and I struggle to find a decent solution. Maybe you can tip me...

I've this simple function in a entity repository, with a simple query:

```
public function findAvailabilityByDr($delivery_round_id) {
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('partial dro.{id}, 
                  partial drp.{id, maxDeliveries, countDeliveries},
                  partial zdd.{id, day},
                  partial rer.{id, maxOrders, countOrders}')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'dro')
        ->leftJoin('dro.parts', 'drp')
        ->leftJoin('drp.day', 'zdd')
        ->leftJoin('drp.relayRounds', 'rer')
        ->where('dro.id = :delivery_round_id')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'delivery_round_id' => $delivery_round_id,
        ));

    dump($qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult());
    die();
}
```

At the first load (with no session cookie created), I got an incomplete result:

```
DeliveryRound {#342 ▼
  -id: 117
  -endOfOrdersDate: DateTime {#346 ▶}
  -parts: PersistentCollection {#428 ▼
    -snapshot: array:2 [ …2]
    -owner: DeliveryRound {#342}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#695 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "deliveryRound"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#373 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#412 ▼
      -elements: array:2 [▼
        0 => DeliveryRoundPart {#425 ▼
          -id: 134
          -deliveryDate: DateTime {#347 ▶}
          -deliveryHourStart: null
          -deliveryHourEnd: null
          -maxDeliveries: null <------ HERE !!!!!!!!!!!
          -countDeliveries: null
          -deliveryRound: DeliveryRound {#342}
          -day: ZoneDeliveryDay {#1302 ▶}
          -ordersCustomers: PersistentCollection {#358 ▶}
          -ordersProviders: PersistentCollection {#410 ▶}
          -relayRounds: PersistentCollection {#637 ▶}
          -roadSheetOptimizationData: null
        }
        1 => DeliveryRoundPart {#1444 ▶}
      ]
    }
    #initialized: true
  }
  -ordersProvidersGenDate: null
  -roadSheetPath: null
  -roadSheetGenDate: null
  -preparationSheetPath: null
  -preparationSheetGenDate: null
  -deliveryMailNotificationsSendingDate: null
  -deliveryNotificationsSendingDate: null
  #translations: PersistentCollection {#420 ▶}
  #newTranslations: null
  #currentLocale: "fr"
  #defaultLocale: "fr"
}
```

And at the second call (refresh), the session cookie is created and the result is correct (maxDeliveries: 30 is a correct value):

```
DeliveryRound {#1657 ▼
  -id: 117
  -endOfOrdersDate: null
  -parts: PersistentCollection {#1794 ▼
    -snapshot: array:2 [ …2]
    -owner: DeliveryRound {#1657}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#695 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "deliveryRound"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1673 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#1795 ▼
      -elements: array:2 [▼
        0 => DeliveryRoundPart {#1747 ▼
          -id: 134
          -deliveryDate: null
          -deliveryHourStart: null
          -deliveryHourEnd: null
          -maxDeliveries: 30 <------ HERE !!!!!!!!!!!
          -countDeliveries: 0
          -deliveryRound: DeliveryRound {#1657}
          -day: ZoneDeliveryDay {#2063 ▶}
          -ordersCustomers: PersistentCollection {#1904 ▶}
          -ordersProviders: PersistentCollection {#1896 ▶}
          -relayRounds: PersistentCollection {#2187 ▶}
          -roadSheetOptimizationData: null
        }
        1 => DeliveryRoundPart {#2188 ▶}
      ]
    }
    #initialized: true
  }
  -ordersProvidersGenDate: null
  -roadSheetPath: null
  -roadSheetGenDate: null
  -preparationSheetPath: null
  -preparationSheetGenDate: null
  -deliveryMailNotificationsSendingDate: null
  -deliveryNotificationsSendingDate: null
  #translations: PersistentCollection {#1799 ▶}
  #newTranslations: null
  #currentLocale: "fr"
  #defaultLocale: "fr"
}
```

And when I use $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult()
the results are correct in both cases.

WTF ? Is it bug ?

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT**

If I reduce it to its simplest expression, with no partial and a call from a controller, the bug is still there...

**Repository:**

```
public function findAvailabilityByDr($delivery_round_id) {
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('dro, 
                  drp')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'dro')
        ->leftJoin('dro.parts', 'drp')
        ->where('dro.id = :delivery_round_id')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'delivery_round_id' => $delivery_round_id,
        ));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class StructureController extends BasePublicCommonController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $delivery_round = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ProxymartDeliveryBundle:DeliveryRound')->findAvailabilityByDr(117);
        dump($delivery_round);
        die();
    }
}
```

This is for things like this I hate programming sometimes :)

Comment: Also deliveryDate is returned at the first call, not at the second call... I never asked for it in the query... It seems that doctrine changes my query when it's the first call. Odd.

Comment: Can you try with selecting `drp.*`

Comment: Same thing... All drp values are null. Works at the 2nd call... :(

Comment: Where is located `findAvailabilityByDr()` ? Can you paste the code calling it.

Comment: Called from a service:

`$delivery_round = $this->em->getRepository('ProxymartDeliveryBundle:DeliveryRound')->findAvailabilityByDr($session_delivery['id']);`

Parameter value is the same in the 2 cases. DQL code is also the same. Why is this correct when I get the result as an array ($qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult()), and not correct when I get it as a Doctrine object ($qb->getQuery()->getResult() or getOneOrNullResult() ) ?

Comment: Try to call the repository directly in a controller to see if it is the same: `$this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('ProxymartDeliveryBundle:DeliveryRo‌​und')->findAvailabilityByDr($session_del‌​ivery['id']);`

Comment: Why are you using partial object? Do you still have the bug if you dump your partial object after doing a `$em->detach`?

Comment: @COil Exactly the same problem from the controller...

Comment: @goto For optimization purpose, but this is a non problem: the same thing occurs when I use full objects (no partial). Same result with detach too.

Comment: I've edited the main post to make the problem simpler... Seems to be a weird bug. I will use the Array response, no choice... and report a bug to Symfony support. Don't know what to do else... Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: What does your `dump()` function do internally? What do you get if you retrieve the value directly (e.g. `var_dump($delivery_round->getDeliveryRoundParts()->first()->getMaxDeliveries())`)?

Comment: Also, do you use result caching, and is it possible that you’re using something from the session or the user object to generate the hash key?

Comment: @lxg no result caching and i'm in dev environment. 
var_dump give a null at the first try, and "30" at the second call. It's such a headache.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html

I don't know about the cookie, but I know for arrayResult():

> The partial object problem in general does not apply to methods or queries where you do not retrieve the query result as objects. Examples are: Query#getArrayResult() [...]

Comment: I'll use it for this particular query since I don't need to persist data this time. But it's still a weird bug. Maybe I could try to update php and sf. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Or maybe I should force a reload when no cookie is detected, since everything is ok when the session cookie is created.

Comment: Yep, sorry i can't help more than that

Comment: You are assuming it is related to cookie but I may not. Try to clear the cache and see if the same bug appears. (NOK, OK, OK, OK, cache clear-> NOK)

Comment: Good idea but no luck, tried to clear dev & prod caches, manually emptied cache directories... still the same.
But you are right: cookie doesnt seem to be the point. Automatic reload has not fixed the issue. I will give it a try on my production server. It's maybe a local bug.